# How to add CSS, Images to a page in CQ5?

Tags: aem, crx

I am creating a new template and then a page from SCRATCH in CQ5. But I can't find the option to add my own CSS/images/JS to the page.

I mean a place to add/upload the actual files.

All the tutorials I've seen talk only about creating a template based on an existing template. Is there any tutorial on how to create the page from scratch ?

Comment: have you added "from scratch" to your google query?

Comment: Yes, and the best result is this page : http://dev.day.com/docs/v5_1/html-resources/cq5_howto_a_collection/cq5_howto_a_collection.html

Comment: I don't know of a tutorial on creating a page template "from scratch."  Since every template depends so much on the CQ5 framework, that seems like a bootless undertaking.  As far as your CSS and JavaScript, see the answer that I am preparing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@David , thanks for your answer, but for now, I got a better way to add and then use external files using WebDAV with CQ5.

The basic integration of WebDAV with CQ5 application is mentioned in [this](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/how_to/webdav_access.html) page

Comment: I agree, Davids answer doesn't really tell you HOW to upload the images to the jcr

Answer (score 5):

Your CSS and JavaScript go into nodes under `/etc/designs/[your project's name]/clientlibs`.  (Ordinarily, you would set the page property `cq:designPath` of your content's home page to be `/etc/designs/[your project's name]` to point to this.)  It's common practice to set up a subfolder of clientlibs called `default`, where your general-purpose style sheets and JavaScript go; you can set up other clientlibs for special-case script and style sheets.  The simplest way to incorporate your script and style sheets into your page template is the `<cq:includeClientLib>` JSP tag.

The Adobe docs on [clientlibs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components/clientlibs.html) will also be useful to you, and explains how to use the tag.